# joining table in h2 database but not able to select data

Tags: sql-server, h2

there is two table:- 1. product 2. batch
-:product  table:-
code  
--------- 
 
001
002
-:Batch  table:-
batchno    productcode  Qty
---------     -----------      -----
B0002              001                   5   
B0003              001                  10  
B0004              001                  15  
C0005              002                  20  
C0034              002                  10  
where batch.qty  integer,product.code varchar(20),batch.product varchar(20).
This code is working in sql server 2008 but not in h2 embeded database.
every fields and its data types are same as in sql server 2008.
i want output like :-
productcode   qty
-----------         ----
001                30
002                30
please help .
thanks in advance.

i am using this query:-
 SELECT product.code,(SELECT sum(batch.qty) FROM batch WHERE batch.productcode = product.code)FROM product;

Answer (score 1):

According to your tables and your required result run the following sql command:

```
SELECT batch.productcode, SUM(batch.qty) FROM batch GROUP BY batch.productcode;
```